# Minimizing or closing a program with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a batch script intended for handling some tasks in my (and a few colleagues) windows startup. The main thing that needs to happen is the killing of a few processes that do to this being a large corporate environment are started as default. They interfere with our work so we have to kill them... I know it's stupid but thats beside the point. This is can not be changed and we have to make due.

I thought about adding some more useful functionality to the script, like starting up certain programs and so on. This all works decently well but the problem i have is that the OUClient won't start minimized. It doesn't open a window (so it is minimized to some extent) but it still appears in the alt-tab list, witch it doesn't when i minimize or close it manually. This is the script:

```
@echo off
C:
cd "C:\Program Files\SysInternals\"

pskill flxps12.exe
pskill flxps17.exe

start /minimized "" "C:\Program Files\Osiris Data\OUClient\OUClient.exe"
start "Outlook" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\OUTLOOK.EXE"
start "Explorer" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

cls
@exit
```

So the question is: **How can I make the OUClient minimize, or even better close** to the system tray (like if you clicked the red x in the upper right) after it is started.

We are running this on Windows XP SP2.

**EDIT:** Everything works fine except the /minimize on OUClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this from batch files directly, but you can write a little helper program which [finds a window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx) and then uses [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548.aspx) to minimize it. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be easily available from VBScript which would have made this a little easier.

Comment: Hm... this is what I was afraid of. I'll take a look at the ShowWindow function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `minimized` switch has a forward slash, not a backslash.

I don't know if OUClient will respect that, but it should.

Answer (score -1):

Have you had a look at the TASKKILL command? A basic example would be

> TASKKILL /IM /F iexplore.exe

(yes, who wouldn't want to kill iexplore? ;-))

Best.

Comment: He wants the program still running, so killing it shouldn't be an option. The window just reacts to trying to close or minimize it; killing the process sidesteps all that.

Comment: But he wants to kill flxps17.exe and flxps12.exe

Comment: Ah, right, overlooked that. But that wasn't his question. And pskill works fine, even though taskkill should be available too on a more recent Windows. Still, if you're not answering the question this should better be a comment.

Comment: sorry for the confusion... The pskill part works fine. Its the OUClinet that is the problem